# How To Click On Telegram Contacts Menu With Pywinauto

Tags: python, telegram, pywinauto

I Want To Click On The Contacts Menu In Telegram With Pywinauto .
I Run This Code But Has Error :

```
>>> import pywinauto
>>> from pywinauto.application import Application
>>> app = Application.start ("C:\Users\Ali\AppData\Roaming\Telegram Desktop\Telegram.exe")
>>> app.Telegram.MenuSelect ("Contacts")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    app.Telegram.MenuSelect ("Contacts")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto-0.5.1-py2.7.egg\pywinauto\application.py", line 244, in __getattr__
    ctrls = _resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto-0.5.1-py2.7.egg\pywinauto\application.py", line 807, in _resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
MatchError: Could not find 'Telegram' in '[]'
>>>
```

How I Can Make This Script ?
Please Answer I Need It .
Thank You .

Comment: This is QT5 application. pywinauto currently supports only native and some basic .NET applications. Probably with future UI Automation API support (plans are about nearest winter) pywinauto will be helpful, but not now.

Comment: Inspect.exe (in UIA mode) can see menus and buttons, but without any names. So special QT support is required to make it as elegant as it's for native apps.

Comment: If you need very simple automation I can suggest only workaround like pressing keys `app.Telegram.TypeKeys("{ENTER}")` and clicking mouse by coordinates like `app.Telegram.ClickInput(coords=(70, 20))`.

Comment: The only open source tool for QT automation I could find is funq: https://github.com/parkouss/funq The project is young but interesting.