# Read content from 3rd party Qt Windows Application

Tags: python, qt, ui-automation

Is it possible to read data/text from an external, 3rd party Qt (5) Windows Application with python (or in general)?

What I tried: pywinauto, but it only "sees" the Main Window, not the Children/Controls.
Most UI Inspection tools also don't see the data of the tables (inspect spyxx accexplorer32 WinSpector WinDetective Uispy ...., Ranorox Spy can see the TableContents, but it is a commercial tool and I only used it for a trial period. Also it is not clear for me how to turn this information into python content. 
The closest question I found was: [How To Click On Telegram Contacts Menu With Pywinauto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31428551/how-to-click-on-telegram-contacts-menu-with-pywinauto)
I discarded https://github.com/parkouss/funq which is mentioned in the comments as it says in the readme, for windows it has to be complied with libFunq which I guess it isn't.

Comment: By default, Qt uses its own rendering layer instead of GDI+, so your typical tools like Spy++ will only see one window for the entire application like you describe here.

Comment: Did you try `Inspect.exe` in UIA mode? Usually can be found in Windows SDK: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64\Inspect.exe` (Win10).

Comment: Also try to set `QT_USE_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1` environment variable before running the app.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. Tested some with QT_USE_NATIVE_WINDOWS=1 which let me see deeper, thnaks for this advice. In some Applications like VLC for example it leads to the wanted effect. In the Application I am trying to get the data unfortunately it doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Answering 7 years later...

I'd recommend using an OCR in Python.
You can use some Python library to automatically take a screenshot of the page, and put the image through an OCR to extract the text.

Then you can try to filter through that text to grab the data you want.

There isn't really a way other than that, as you're asking about 3rd party applications which are already compiled.

https://noob3xploiter.medium.com/game-hacking-with-python-and-cheat-engine-5000369e27b9

^ This is also a good article, as although it applies to games, you could actually use the same example to grab the text directly from the RAM/memory.

Probably doing something like using cheat engine to find where the text is saved in the memory, and then grabbing the memory address and putting it into Python. (There is a way to make it work, even if you close and open the application again, I just don't know off the top of my head how).

So, those are the two main methods.

1. An OCR with python

Get a library to take a screenshot the application's window

Download a library to grab the text from the sreenshot (OCR)

A library to help automate button clicks, and go through the UI (probably pywinauto)

2. Cheat Engine with Python

You first manually use Cheat Engine to grab where in the memory of the application are the strings saved.

You'd have to learn how to make the "Cheat" work even if you open and close the application

You put the memory address in Python using a library, and you should be able to grab whatever strings are saved there. Potentially even numbers/floats or anything that's saved within the memory. I doubt the applications have an anti-cheat on them haha.